# rename command for replacing text in filename from a certain point (character), but only up to, and maintaining the file extension

Tags: linux, command, file-rename, batch-rename

I've got a ton of files as follows

```
audiofile_drums_1-ktpcwybsh5c.wav
soundsample_drums_2-fghlkjy57sa.wav
noise_snippet_guitar_5-mxjtgqta3o1.wav
louder_flute_9-mdlsiqpfj6c.wav
```

I want to remove everything between and including the "-" and the .wav file extension, to be left with

```
audiofile_drums_1.wav
soundsample_drums_2.wav
noise_snippet_guitar_5.wav
louder_flute_9.wav
```

I've tried to do delete everything following and including the character "-" using

```
rename 's/-.*//' *
```

Which gives me

```
audiofile_drums_1
soundsample_drums_2
noise_snippet_guitar_5
louder_flute_9
```

And for lack of finding an easy way to rename all the files again, adding .wav the extension, I am hoping there is a slicker way to do this in one nifty command in one stage instead of 2.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please don't include "thanks" or similar in questions. See here: meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/… and here: meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works in my specific case, but should work for any file extension.

```
rename -n 's/-.*(?=\.wav$)//' *
```

The command looks for all characters after and inclusive of the `-` symbol in the filename, then, using a positive lookahead** `(?=\.wav$)` to search for the characters (the file extension in this case) at the end of the filename (denoted by `$`, and replaces them with no characters (removing them).

** **NOTE:** A positive look ahead is a zero width assertion.
It will affect the match but it will not be included
in the replacement. (The '.wav' part will not be
erased)

In this example `(?=\.wav$)` is the positive lookahead.  The dollar sign $, as in regex, denotes at the end of the line, so perfect for a file extension.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rename 's/-[^\.]*\.wav$/\.wav/' *`

The first part `-[^\.]*\.wav$` searchs for a - followed by n chars that are not `.` followed by `.wav` and the end of filename. The end of filename and `.wav` is not strictly needed but it helps avoid renaming files you don't want to rename.

The `/\.wav/` preserves the extension.

Please not that `rename` is not a standard utility, and is part of perl, so `rename` may not be available on every linux system.

Comment: I figured out another similar approach before i saw your answer, which worked really well, In which it preserves the extension, but could also still be used to substitute the found character string if required.

Comment: Upvote any answers you found helpful, and accept the "best" answer. I would usually say the one you end up using is the "best".